# Prisma Postgres stopped working out of sudden, saying database string is invalid

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, next.js, prisma, vercel

I was debugging my Next.js project with Prisma as my ORM. Everything was working fine.
I logged into the dashboard page which lists all products from the Vercel Postgres database by using Prisma client.

Out of sudden, Prisma stopped working and no data can be fetched, basically any operations via Prisma error out. Here is an error example:

```
Invalid `prisma.artworks.findMany()` invocation:


The provided database string is invalid. The provided arguments are not supported in database URL. Please refer to the documentation in https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/database-reference/connection-urls for constructing a correct connection string. In some cases, certain characters must be escaped. Please check the string for any illegal characters.
```

I have not changed anything in the `.env` or `.env.local` files, I did not even open those 2 files. So I opened the Vercel website, and copied the database connection strings again and put it into these 2 environment config files,

```
POSTGRES_URL="postgres://default:<mypassword>@ep-divine-smoke-00439065-pooler.us-east-1.postgres.vercel-storage.com:5432/verceldb"
POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL="postgres://default:<mypassword>@ep-divine-smoke-00439065-pooler.us-east-1.postgres.vercel-storage.com:5432/verceldb?pgbouncer=true&connect_timeout=15"
POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING="postgres://default:<mypassword>@ep-divine-smoke-00439065.us-east-1.postgres.vercel-storage.com:5432/verceldb"
POSTGRES_USER="default"
POSTGRES_HOST="ep-divine-smoke-00439065-pooler.us-east-1.postgres.vercel-storage.com"
POSTGRES_PASSWORD="<mypassword>"
POSTGRES_DATABASE="verceldb"
```

(I replaced the real password with `<mypassword>` in this post, but the real env files have the correct password which I copied from Vercel without any change).

Also copied the code for use in Prisma's schema file like below:

```
datasource db {    
  provider = "postgresql"    
  url = env("POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL") // uses connection pooling    
  directUrl = env("POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING") // uses a direct connection    
}
```

---

**Update 1**

I just notice that I can pull my db schema from the Vercel PostgreSql database, this means the database connection string actually works. The issue could come from the Vercel or Prisma?

[image]

**Update 2**

Here is the globally installed Prisma version

```
>npx prisma --version

Environment variables loaded from .env
prisma                  : 5.9.1
@prisma/client          : 5.9.1
Computed binaryTarget   : windows
Operating System        : win32
Architecture            : x64
Node.js                 : v20.9.0
Query Engine (Node-API) : libquery-engine 23fdc5965b1e05fc54e5f26ed3de66776b93de64 (at node_modules\@prisma\engines\query_engine-windows.dll.node)
Schema Engine           : schema-engine-cli 23fdc5965b1e05fc54e5f26ed3de66776b93de64 (at node_modules\@prisma\engines\schema-engine-windows.exe)
Schema Wasm             : @prisma/prisma-schema-wasm 5.9.0-32.23fdc5965b1e05fc54e5f26ed3de66776b93de64
Default Engines Hash    : 23fdc5965b1e05fc54e5f26ed3de66776b93de64
Studio                  : 0.497.0
```

Which is the same as saved in my `package.json` file for this project.

**Update 3**

Also, I am able to launch the Prisma Studio and see all the data. So this is for sure the issue from `PrismaClient`.

**Update 4**

I finally made it working ~!

I just found that if I pasted in the connection string into the `schema.prisma` like below and re-run `npx prisma generate`, it start to work.

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = "postgres://default:<mypassword>@ep-divine-smoke-00439065-pooler.us-east-1.postgres.vercel-storage.com:5432/verceldb?pgbouncer=true&connect_timeout=15&sslmode=require"
}
```

So now I suspect that the `env()` method somehow stopped working out of sudden in `schema.prisma` file and this is the cause of the issue.

How to fix it?

Comment: `npx prisma` invokes the globally installed prisma instance, whereas in your Next project the local instance is used. If they are of different versions they may have different behaviors. Could you double check the versions of the local and global prisma? Try again after making sure that they are aligned to the same version may solve the problem

Comment: @xiao thanks man. found it, they are the same version `5.9.1`

Comment: Also, I am sure the issue comes from Prisma now as shown in `Update 3`.